# Ошибка сборки Gradle с OpenCV

Tags: java, android, opencv

У меня подключена библиотека OpenCV и при сборке gradle выходит такая ошибка:

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':openCVLibrary3413:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    > Could not read entry ':openCVLibrary3413:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' from cache 
    executionHistory.bin
```

А вот 2ая ошибка:

```
    Unable to read serialized file fingerprint. Unrecognized value found in the data stream.
```

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить `./gradlew --stop`, потом `./gradlew clean`, потом удалить директорию `.gradle` в вашем проекте. После чего собрать проект заново.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне помогло обновление gradle, увидел в студии уведомление о доступном обновлении, после обновления всё заработало

Answer (score 0):

[Попробуйте](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38431974) удалить директорию `.gradle` в вашем проекте (не cпутайте с `.gradle` в домашней директории). И собрать проект заново.